# Error with <rrouter-outlet> by running Karma test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angular-material2

Hello I am new with Angular, Material and Karma, I build a small application an run a test. I add all the needed modules in my app.componente.ts but reach the error below.

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
</div>
<div md-content>
    [ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@6:4
```

Here is a list of all imports in my app.component.

**Importes of app.component.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {Http, HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {  MdSidenavModule, MdButtonModule, MdInputModule, MdCardModule, MdMenuModule, MdToolbarModule, MdIconModule,
  MdCardContent, MdToolbar, MdToolbarRow, MdToolbarBase
} from '@angular/material'


imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true } ),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdInputModule
  ],
```

I have no idea how I can fix this. Does someone can give me a hint?

**UPDATE**
This is the test.

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

app.component.html

```
<div layout="row">
    <div md-toolbar color="primary">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    </div> </div> <div md-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> </div>
```

Comment: And, what is the code of your test?

Comment: OK. So what you put in your app module is irrelevant. Your test uses a module containing just one thing: the AppComponent. Nothing else. No import, no provider, nothing, since what you pass to configureTestingModule() is a module definition declaring only the AppComponent. Add RouterTestingModule to the imports of the module definition passed to configureTestingModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ], imports: [RouterTestingModule], // <--- 
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: the `RouterTestingModule`  was missing. after import this class it works.

Comment: Sorry for the missing comment, thanks michael-mammut